# Which menu module will show both image and link in submenu?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-navigation

I want to display image and link in sub menu, i tried menu icon module, but i can not able to display both image and link.

can any one know which module support both?

i found one drupal website which uses the same, sweetdigital.co

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before by overriding [theme_menu_link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) to add a wrapper and a unique id, then just used css to add the image using the unique id as the selector.

Comment: i don't know to implement this and very confusing. Can you please paste the code i have to use for theme_menu_link. its a nice idea for image to appear, thanks for that!!!